# Unable to record video with RPi-Cam-Web-Interface with USB mounted

Tags: pi-3b+

I am trying to record a video using RPi-Cam-Web-Interface on my Raspberry Pi model 3 B+ and saving it on my thumb-drive.

However, when trying to record a video with my thumb-drive mounted to `/var/www/html/media` it gives me an error

```
mmal: mmal_port_disable: port vc.ril.video_encode:out:0(H264)(0x1234300) is not enabled
```

I tried changing `gpu_mem=192` in `/boot/config.txt` and rebooting the Raspberry Pi but it still is giving me the error `mmal: mmal_port_disable`

Comment: is the error really dependent on the thumb drive?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get it to work with FAT32 so I reformatted my thumb-drive to ext4. Then I created a directory to mount the usb to using:

```
mkdir /media/usb
```

and then editing the `etc/fstab` and adding to the bottom of the file (where xxxx-xxxx-xxxx is the UUID of the partition of the drive you are using):

```
UUID=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx /path/to/usb ext4 defaults 0 0
/path/to/usb /var/www/html/media/ none bind 0 0
```

I also found that I had to give permissions to write to my usb using:

`sudo chown www-data:www-data /path/to/usb`